# Navigation bar color ios15

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationbarappearance

I have problem with changing navigation bar color in iOS 15.
In AppDelegate I'm setting UINavigationBarAppearence like this:

```
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
appearance.shadowColor = .clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

In my application, I need to change navigation bar color in multiple places in multiple colors.

Previously, just setting `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .yellow`

did the trick but not anymore. Every time when I need to change navigation bar color, do I need to change whole `UINavigationBarAppearence` class attributes? If yes, it seems like a bit overload. But I cannot find better solution.
Others methods like

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

dont work anymore too. Instead

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

only works. All these change just seems very confusing.

Comment: can you attach some pic you have expected?

Comment: "Every time when I need to change navigation bar color, do I need to change whole UINavigationBarAppearence class attributes" Basically yes, but you can apply them to `navigationItem` of a single view controller.

Comment: @matt can you share some code? For example, for changing bar color.

Comment: I don't see how to make it clearer.  Make another UINavigationBarAppearance and say `navigationItem.standardAppearance = ...` The bar color is the appearance's `backgroundColor`.

Comment: And whats the best approach to change navigation bar title?